# How to redefine \alpha as a command that takes parameters in Latex?

Tags: macros, environments, texmaker

So, I've been trying to *renewcommand* `\alpha` by assigning it parameters in Latex. This is what I have for my preamble and the body...(seen below). On line 12, I attempted to create such a "function", but I continue to get the following errors

for line 14:
 `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].\alpha #1->\alpha (#1) ...\mathcal{C}^{\infty})\) is a map \(\alpha:`

and for line 1: `! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`
Can someone please help!?

````
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym, braket, amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb,amsthm, mathtools, standalone, setspace, graphicx, tikz, pgfplots, nccmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\Def}{\underline{\textbf{Definition:}}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\roman{enumiii}}
\renewenvironment{proof}{\textbf{Proof:}\setlength{\parindent}{5em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}}{\hfill \qedsymbol}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\renewcommand{\sup}[1]{\mathrm{sup}(#1)}
\renewcommand{\inf}[1]{\mathrm{inf}(#1)}
\renewcommand{\alpha}[1]{\alpha(#1)}
\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon}
\usepackage{anysize}\marginsize{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\author{Dwight Dinkins}
\title{DIfferential Geometry ITCP: Lecture 1}
\date{March 19, 2020}
\setstretch{2}%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\Def A differentiable curve \((\mathcal{C}^{\infty})\) is a map \(\alpha: I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}\), \(I=(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}\), such that \[\alpha{t}=( x(t), y(t),z(t))\), \(x,y,z\) are \(\mathcal{C}^{\infty}\) functions.
\end{document}```
````

Comment: You can't do it like that, you need first to copy the current definition like  `\let\oldalpha=\alpha` and then `\renewcommand{\alpha}[1]{\oldalpha(#1)}`.

Comment: You can redefine `\alpha` as in the comments of @campa, but I don't believe this is what you want. First you call `\alpha` a differentiable curve and you don't want any kind of bracket here, then you want `\alpha(...)`and call both by the same name. You can do it any way with a optional parameter but I believe it is better to call the second one by other name, say `\newcommand{\al}[1]{\alpha(#1)}` or anything else. Same comments on `\inf`and `\sup`.

Comment: That is not a good idea, give your macro a different name.  Also your proof env redefinition isn't good as the end marker placement can easily fail in this naïve redefinition (a lot of people have tried to do it like this and learnt why it is not recommended)

Comment: @daleif Could you elaborate on my redefinition of my proof environment? Thanks you all  for the help?

Comment: If the text is just right then the qed marker goes to the next line, but at the left edge, the `\hfill` is ignored, that looks inconsistent and is annoying having to check by hand.

Comment: Note that even without the `\alpha` loop the MWE cannot compile, there is no documentclass and you have a `\[` where you probably wanted `\(`

Comment: Also Nobody nowadays uses underline to hightlight stufff, use a proper theorem construction, it comes with numbers that are referable. As with a lot of the other stuff in this example, don't reinvent the wheel, it is a waste of your time.

Comment: With the margins in your example (aka add `article` doc class and remove the `alpha` loop` then `\begin{proof}
  test \hspace{0.77\textwidth} test 
\end{proof}` is enough to show the problem with that `proof` env.

Comment: Additionally, be careful with such a wide text width, it hurts readability.